# bazel build Error: Cannot locate python.exe

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, bazel

I'm trying to build bazel using the following approach in mysys64. I found this at [tensorflow-mnist-test](https://github.com/kalaspuffar/tensorflow-mnist-test)

```
cd [bazel-dist-dir]
pacman -Syuu gcc git curl zip unzip zlib-devel
export BAZEL_WRKDIR=c:/tempdir/shrtpath
export BAZEL_SH=c:/tools/msys64/usr/bin/bash.exe
export BAZEL_VS=c:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 14.0
export BAZEL_PYTHON=c:/Python36/python.exe
./compile.sh
./compile.sh compile output/bazel.exe
```

However `mysys2` gives an error when I try to compile. It says it cannot locate my `python.exe`. This is so strange because the file is in the path I provide. Does anybody what is going on here? I also tried the message giving in the error but nothing work. How can I solve this?

```
Master Tk@DESKTOP-BJH5T82 MSYS /C/Users/Master 
TK/Downloads/tensorflow_compilation/bazel-0.11.1
$ ./compile.sh
ERROR: cannot locate python.exe; check your PATH.
   You may need to run the following command, or something
   similar, depending on where you installed Python:
     export PATH="/c/Python27:$PATH"
```

Comment: Please don't post images of exceptions.
Copy and paste instead.

Comment: My bad. I edited the question.

Comment: I upvoted because you edited the question correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set the Python PATH yet.
This command would work

```
export PATH="/your/python/exe/directory"
```

Or (like your terminal is saying)

```
export PATH="/c/Python27:$PATH"
```